N-MOS failing short on my PCB
I'm currently testing a PCB I designed. One of the MOSFETs, Q5, failed yesterday for the 3rd time, and I haven't managed yet to find out why.
Main facts:

N-channel MOSFET: CSD19538Q2T
Rated (never exceed): Vds<100V; -20V<Vgs<20V; Id_cotinuous@25°C<13.1A
operation range (both measured and theoretical: both agree): 0V < Vds <5.5V; 0V < Vgs < 5V; Id<1mA (theoretical, not measured)
failure mode: "short-circuit" between gate and source (resistance in the 10-30 ohms range)
ambient temperature: <60°C (highest measured: 50°C)

So the question is: why does Q5 fail from time to time (3 failures for maybe 200 hours of runtime)? What to do next to identify the problem?
The schematics:



Some explanations about the circuit:
Vdd is the main supply voltage for my board. It comes either from an external DC supply (20-60V range, usually 24V), or from the PoE (power over ethernet) circuit represented on the 3rd schematics (which results in Vdd=57V).
The IC U10 handles the PoE negotiations. It has an open drain output signal, PWR_GD = POWER_GOOD, that it pulls to GND until PoE negotiations finished successfully. In case of an external DC supply, U10 detects it (through the AUX pin), and also stops pulling POWER_GOOD to GND.
POWER_GOOD is pulled high to Vdd (through R30=27k), but limited to about 4.7V by the zener diode D12.
The power good signal is then used for exactly 4 things:

input for U9 (to fully enable the ideal diode bridge, instead of relying on the intrinsic diodes of the MOSFETs)
power the LED D13
enable the PS2 DC/DC converter: Q5 pulls down the ON/OFF pin of PS2
enable the PS3 DC/DC converter: Q7 pulls down the ON/OFF pin of PS2

Layout:




Q5 is very near the big, shielded, common mode choke L2: might it be a problem of magnetic fields?
Links to the datasheets:

the MOSFETs: Q5, Q7 and Q8-16: CSD19538Q2T
the DC/DC converter PS2: PKU5311EPI (5V 7A version)
the DC/DC converter PS3: TMR 3-4811WIR
the PoE management IC: U10: LT4294IDD#TRPBF
the ideal diode bridge controler U9: LT4321IUF#PBF
the L2 common mode choke (inductor) sitting next to Q5: CM6518-ALD

Scope traces:
NB : my scope has isolated channels, so the grounds of both channels can be different

Red: Vdd (power supply from lab supply, with respect to GND_ALIM), Violet: POWER_GOOD signal (with respect to PS2M, ie the source of Q5). Trace taken at power up

Red: Vdd (power supply from lab supply, with respect to GND_ALIM), Violet: POWER_GOOD signal (with respect to PS2M, ie the source of Q5). Trace taken at power down

Red: Vdd (power supply from lab supply, with respect to GND_ALIM), Violet: Vds of Q5(with respect to PS2M, ie the source of Q5). Trace taken at power up

Red: Vdd (power supply from lab supply, with respect to GND_ALIM), Violet: Vds of Q5(with respect to PS2M, ie the source of Q5). Trace taken at power down
Do you have any idea what make cause Q5 to fail short (between gate and source) from time to time (while Q7 seems fine)? Any idea what tests/measurements to make to narrow down the issue? Or modifications that might help preventing the problem?
Feel free to ask for any additional information you think might be useful.
EDIT:
As several of you noted, the source of Q5 is instead connected to PS2M net instead of GND_ALIM (there is a common mode choke between GND_ALIM and PS2M).
I did a measurement of PS2M (with respect to GND_ALIM):
.
Note that there is only a moderate load on the PS2 converter. I will try to do the setup for high load, but it will probably have to wait until Monday.
EDIT2:
I tested with a high load. There seem to be no significant increase in the voltage between GND_ALIM and PS2M. One picture is with low load, the other one with high load (sorry, I got mixed up in which is which, but you can seen there is no real difference).
Channel 1 (red): PS2M with respect to GND_ALIM
Channel 4 (violet): POWER_GOOD with respect to PS2M
So the fact that the noise level don't increases makes it seem less likely that the difference PS2M-GND_ALIM is big enough to exceed the Vgs of Q5 (Vgs is 0-5V nominal, so with 1V noise, it's -1 to +6V: we are still very far away from the +-20V limit.
Any idea how to investigate further (or to mitigate the problem on the existing prototypes)?
On the next revision, I think I will just throw in an optocoupler instead of Q5 to be sure.


EDIT3 :
I did some additional measurements using the PoE++ supply instead of the 24V supply. Most of the time, everything is OK, but from time to time, I get big voltage differences between GND_ALIM and PS2M. So far, the biggest I noticed was +18.8V (near the never exceed value of 20V) and -27.1V (so exceeding the -20V limit by 7.1V).
What's very strange, is that the voltage differences sometimes start BEFORE the voltage rises (or maybe it's some kind of bouncing while connecting the Ethernet connector?).


For both images :

Red : test_point T6 : POE (with respect to GND_Alim)
Violet : PS2M with respect to GND_Alim
trigger on rising edge of POE

So it seems now clear that hose differences between PS2M and GND_ALIM cause the Vgs of Q5 to exceed its never exceed values.
I have no idea however so far why I get those spikes BEFORE the rising of the POE voltage. Is it due to PoE negotiation? To contact bouncing while connecting the Ethernet connector? Something else? (If you think it's better to do a separate question, feel free to tell me)
EDIT4 :
at @Rohat Kılıç's request, I did the same test again with minimal loop (about 1cm²). The results are similar (I managed to capture a +25.2V spike)


What do you use as scope ground reference? Please note GND_ALIM is reference for the signal and clamp zener, but the Q5 source is at PS2M. There is a CM choke in between. Measure with scope PS2M voltage in reference to GND_ALIM, or simply measure Vgs with scope that has no comnection to GND_ALIM.

Where is the device located that the ambient temperature gets as high as 50 °C? Such hot environments sound like something automotive or industrial, where there might be other concerns going on besides temperature.

@Justme : I just edited my post to add the ground references (my scope has isolated channels) : Vdd was measured with respect to GND_Alim, Vds and powergood with repect to PS2M.
I added a measurement PS2M with respect of GND_ALIM.

@Hearth : it's the first prototype of a subsea camera. So the casing is water (and air) tight. The biggest heat source has a direct thermal bridge to the casing, but I haven't added one (yet) for the DC/DC converters (will be added soon). So when the camera is in water, the casing is cooled by water, but in air it gets pretty hot.

@Sandro Okay, that makes sense. Shouldn't be much noise other than that generated within the device, then. Probably less than most things on land, really; seawater makes for pretty good EMI shielding!

I added comparison of GND_ALIM vs PS2M with low vs high load on the PS2 converter : no visible difference on the noise level. So with just <1V of noise, it's hard to belive I manage to reach the never exceed values of Vgs of Q5 (it would require at least 15V of noise)

Is your load dynamic? During long hours of operation, is it common to draw very low current for some time then immediately start higher currents? I'm asking this because in such a case the voltage difference can be huge momentarily.

The biggest load is the SoM, which power consumption changes when launching/stopping the program (and I suppose at smaller time scales when blocked by some I/O operations). I will try to calculate the maximal possible voltage difference supposing the SoM goes from maximal power to 0W instanteanously and just taking into account the capacitors. Let's see if this can explain the issue.

I added 2 extra graphs using the PoE++ supply instead of the 24V supply : I managed to capture variations of +18.8V and -27.1V between PS2M and GND_ALIM : so this is certainly the cause of the failure of Q5. But I stil don't know WHY I get those spikes, particularly since they sometimes occur before the POE voltage starts to rise. Cf EDIT3 in the original post. Does anyone have an idea?


what make cause Q5 to fail short (between gate and source) from time to time (while Q7 seems fine) ?

I see a voltage reference issue here.
Your POWER_GOOD signal is referenced to GND_ALIM. For Q7, the DC-DC converter that the MOSFET controls (PS3) uses GND_ALIM as VIN– i.e. referenced to GND_ALIM. Q7's source pin is connected to GND_ALIM, so driving the MOSFET directly from the POWER_GOOD signal is not a problem.
But for Q5, it's different. The gate signal is referenced to GND_ALIM but the source is connected to somewhere else, effectively: The -V_IN pin of the PS2 (the DC-DC converter that Q5 controls) can be swinging up and down with respect to GND_ALIM (because it's a switching power supply so expect noise!) although they can be thought of as a short at DC.
What I am trying to say is, that you may have a varying gate-source voltage for Q5 because of a possibly noisy -V_IN pin of PS2. If it exceeds the specified limits it may die. This may not be expected to happen straight away but can happen at a random time.

Indeed, when using the PoE++ supply, I sometimes get differences between PS2M and GND_ALIM big enough to exceed the ratings of Q5. But I have no idea why I get those spikes (in particular not why they sometimes occur before the PoE voltage is rising)

@Sandro please first make sure you did the correct probing there because during the startup of any switching regulator there can be radiations, and your probe's ground clip/cord may pick them up and show misleading waveforms. Other than that, since your PS2 module and its associated filter will be seen as a very large capacitive load to your PoE regulator, there can be current spikes during start up. See the small increase in output voltage the moment the spikes first appear (both images).

indeed, I was using a rather big loop. I did the measurement again with minimal loop (as on the picture of the post you linked to), and still get huge spikes (I added a screenshot of a +25.2V spike obtained using the very short ground clip). So the measurement don't seem to be the problem.

The 4.7V diode clamp is with respect to GND_ALIM, not GND_ISO, so I wouldn't trust it to clamp Q5's \$V_{GS}\$.
Also, the POWER_GOOD signal is horribly noisy, 500mV pk-pk. It doesn't seem like it's coming from \$V_{DD}\$, which looks clean.
The noise suggests that the relationship between GND_ALIM and GND_ISO PS2M may not be as close as you think. I would recommend looking for spikes in the potential difference between GND_ALIM and GND_ISO PS2M. Such spikes would render D12's protection useless to Q5.

GND_ISO isn't the ground used for Q5's source. Q5's source is connected to PS2M net. But otherwise your reasoning holds. And the difference between GND_Alim and PS2M might indeed be the problem : I will look into it.

@Sandro Ah yes, my mistake, sorry. Then I suspect the CM choke is doing its job very well, and causing Q5's source potential (PS2M) to be very different from GND_ALIM.

it seems indeed to do a good job. I get up to 0.75V difference between GND_ALIM and PS2M on an "idle" PCB (about 10W). I will try to find a way to test it under heavy load, where I expect it to get even worse (it might take me some time, the only completely fitted setup is the one in which Q5 just failed)

When using the PoE++ supply, I sometimes get differences between PS2M and GND_ALIM big enough to exceed the ratings of Q5. But I have no idea why I get those spikes (in particular not why they sometimes occur before the PoE voltage is rising)

Until you can capture an event which shows clear electrical overstress, any potential causes of failure are speculative.
I see several areas of concern:

You should never connect MOSFET gates directly together. You should have at least a few ohms between POWER_GOOD and the gates of Q5 and Q7. Driving them without series resistance can cause them to ring and you may get weird interactions.

You should have a pull-down resistor from each gate to its source to provide a discharge path for the gate if it is not being actively driven. The gates can drift up to turn-on potential if they are left floating. If they don't need to turn on and off super-fast you could also add a small capacitor in parallel with the pull-down resistor.


I would guess that under some strange circumstance you may be exceeding Vgs. You may want to install individual gate clamps close to the package (and on the MOSFET-side of the series resistors).
